# Есть ли в kivy python функция пока касается есть on_touch_down но это только в момент прикосновения и on_touch_move но это только когда двигается?

Tags: android, python, kivy

Я делаю игру на kivy под android и та имеется джойстик который работает неправильно.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget



Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0")
Config.set("graphics", "height", "900")
Config.set("graphics", "width", "1800")


def dvigatell(b):
   global a
   if b.y > -300:
     a.y += (-300 - b.y) / -10
   elif b.y < -300:
       a.y -= (-300 - b.y) / 10
   if b.x > 750:
     a.x += (b.x - 750) / 10
   elif b.x < 750:
       a.x -= (b.x - 750) / -10

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
       gun = FloatLayout(size = (2000, 1000))

       gun.add_widget(Image(source="cvtest.png"))
       global a
       a = (Image(source="iii.png", pos = (0, 0)))
       gun.add_widget(a)

       c = (Image(source="iy.png", pos = (750, -300)))
       gun.add_widget(c)

       global b
       b = (Image(source="gor.png", pos = (750, -300)))
       gun.add_widget(b)

       gun.add_widget(MyPaintWidget())

       gun.add_widget(Button(text='<<<#>>>',
           background_color = [.24,.70,.25, 1],
           background_normal = "",
           on_press = self.add_number, 
           size_hint = (0.08, 0.1),
           pos = (100, 50)));

       return gun

   def add_number(self, instance): 

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
       global b

       if 600 < (touch.x - 900) < 900 and -450 < (touch.y - 450) < -150:


         b.pos = (touch.x - 900, touch.y - 450)
         dvigatell(b)
         super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch) 
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
       if 600 < (touch.x - 900) < 900 and -450 < (touch.y - 450) < -150:


         b.pos = (touch.x - 900, touch.y - 450)
         while b.pos != (750, -300):
              dvigatell(b)
    def on_touch_up(self, touch): 
       p = False
       b.pos = (750, -300)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример класса, который реализует закрытие изображения путем свайпа вниз, как это сделано на многих сайтах социальных сетей. Захват, касание, снятие фокуса. Думаю, вам для примера подойдет. Хотя вопрос, честно говоря, не совсем ясен.

```
class MovingImage(AsyncImage):
    previous_image = ObjectProperty()

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        '''Вызывается при захвате изображения.'''

        if touch.grab_current is self:
            ...

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        '''Вызывается при снятии захвата с изображения.'''

        if touch.grab_current is self: 
            touch.ungrab(self)
            ....

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):     
            touch.grab(self)
```